# How to show in product listing page the downloadable link title and price?

Tags: product-list, downloadable

I am a newbee in this forum. Thanks for evrybody for your help.

I have a probem. In Catalog Product List , I want to modify the template/catalog/product/list.phtml . In that page I want to show for each product if it is 'downloadable' type, the Link Title and the Link Price.

Thanks

Comment: accept the answer if it helped you to solve the problem. Don't leave a question as it is

Comment: dont put comments as anwer. There is provision to add comments just below every answer. If you need assistance more, you can edit your own question or raise another question here

Comment: Hello gays excuses me I am new here, that's the first time I ask question.Thanks for helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thoma Louis,

You can this by below step:
create `Listlinks.php` file under `app>code>local>Mage>Downloadable>Block>Catalog>Product`
and code this file:

```
<?php
class Mage_Downloadable_Block_Catalog_Product_Listlinks extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract
{
    /**
     * Enter description here...
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
       public function setProduct($product) {
        $this->_product = $product;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getProduct() {
        return $this->_product;
    }
    public function getLinksPurchasedSeparately()
    {
        return $this->getProduct()->getLinksPurchasedSeparately();
    }

    /**
     * Enter description here...
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function getLinkSelectionRequired()
    {
        return $this->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)
            ->getLinkSelectionRequired($this->getProduct());
    }

    /**
     * Enter description here...
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function hasLinks()
    {
        return $this->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)
            ->hasLinks($this->getProduct());
    }

    /**
     * Enter description here...
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getLinks()
    {
        return $this->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)
            ->getLinks($this->getProduct());
    }

    /**
     * Enter description here...
     *
     * @param Mage_Downloadable_Model_Link $link
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFormattedLinkPrice($link)
    {
        $price = $link->getPrice();
        $store = $this->getProduct()->getStore();

        if (0 == $price) {
            return '';
        }

        $taxCalculation = Mage::getSingleton('tax/calculation');
        if (!$taxCalculation->getCustomer() && Mage::registry('current_customer')) {
            $taxCalculation->setCustomer(Mage::registry('current_customer'));
        }

        $taxHelper = Mage::helper('tax');
        $coreHelper = $this->helper('core');
        $_priceInclTax = $taxHelper->getPrice($link->getProduct(), $price, true);
        $_priceExclTax = $taxHelper->getPrice($link->getProduct(), $price);

        $priceStr = '<span class="price-notice">+';
        if ($taxHelper->displayPriceIncludingTax()) {
            $priceStr .= $coreHelper->currencyByStore($_priceInclTax, $store);
        } elseif ($taxHelper->displayPriceExcludingTax()) {
            $priceStr .= $coreHelper->currencyByStore($_priceExclTax, $store);
        } elseif ($taxHelper->displayBothPrices()) {
            $priceStr .= $coreHelper->currencyByStore($_priceExclTax, $store);
            if ($_priceInclTax != $_priceExclTax) {
                $priceStr .= ' (+'.$coreHelper
                    ->currencyByStore($_priceInclTax, $store).' '.$this->__('Incl. Tax').')';
            }
        }
        $priceStr .= '</span>';

        return $priceStr;
    }

    /**
     * Returns price converted to current currency rate
     *
     * @param float $price
     * @return float
     */
    public function getCurrencyPrice($price)
    {
        $store = $this->getProduct()->getStore();
        return $this->helper('core')->currencyByStore($price, $store, false);
    }

    /**
     * Enter description here...
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getJsonConfig()
    {
        $config = array();
        $coreHelper = Mage::helper('core');

        foreach ($this->getLinks() as $link) {
            $config[$link->getId()] = $coreHelper->currency($link->getPrice(), false, false);
        }

        return $coreHelper->jsonEncode($config);
    }

    public function getLinkSamlpeUrl($link)
    {
        return $this->getUrl('downloadable/download/linkSample', array('link_id' => $link->getId()));
    }

    /**
     * Return title of links section
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLinksTitle()
    {
        if ($this->getProduct()->getLinksTitle()) {
            return $this->getProduct()->getLinksTitle();
        }
        return Mage::getStoreConfig(Mage_Downloadable_Model_Link::XML_PATH_LINKS_TITLE);
    }

    /**
     * Return true if target of link new window
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function getIsOpenInNewWindow()
    {
        return Mage::getStoreConfigFlag(Mage_Downloadable_Model_Link::XML_PATH_TARGET_NEW_WINDOW);
    }

    /**
     * Returns whether link checked by default or not
     *
     * @param Mage_Downloadable_Model_Link $link
     * @return bool
     */
    public function getIsLinkChecked($link)
    {
        $configValue = $this->getProduct()->getPreconfiguredValues()->getLinks();
        if (!$configValue || !is_array($configValue)) {
            return false;
        }

        return $configValue && (in_array($link->getId(), $configValue));
    }

    /**
     * Returns value for link's input checkbox - either 'checked' or ''
     *
     * @param Mage_Downloadable_Model_Link $link
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLinkCheckedValue($link)
    {
        return $this->getIsLinkChecked($link) ? 'checked' : '';
    }
}
```

And add **the below code in list.phtml**

```
   <?php if($_product->getTypeId()=='downloadable'):?>
                    <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('downloadable/catalog_product_listlinks')->setTemplate('downloadable/catalog/product/links.phtml')->setProduct($_product)->toHtml();?>

                    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Hello Hamit, I am very neew here, now I learn how to use the forum! Excuse me and thanks for your helpfull help